# Managing active state

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

On click, I'd like to addclass `active` to the parent li element while also removing the `active` class from any other element which may be active already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("li a").click( function() {
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: This will also add the `active` class to the anchor tag, not the parent li.

Comment: I think it should be $(this).parent().addClass('active') to add the active class to the <li> element?

Comment: @Nimbuz: You are right. @Matt: you are right, too. Both mistakes fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.filter').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
  var theLi = $(this).closest('li');

  theLi.siblings('.active:first').removeClass('active');
  theLi.addClass('active');

  $('ul.items li').hide().filter('.' + this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf("#") + 1)).show();

  event.preventDefault();
});
```